# Math Olympiad Geometry Question: Similar Triangles

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> In the diagram below, △ABC and △CDE are two right-angled triangles
>   with AC = 24, CE =7 and ∠ ACB = ∠ CED. Find the length of the line
>   segment AE.
>
> [image: Diagram:]
>
> The above is the diagram.

I came across this question in a Math Olympiad Competition. I am able to find out that △ABC and △CDE are similar triangles but after that, I am not sure what to do to solve the question. Can anyone help me with the solution? Thanks.

Comment: What can you say about $\angle ACE$?

Comment: It is equal to 90 degrees?

Comment: @snivysteel Yes.

Comment: Now use Pythagorean theorem: $$7^2+24^2=(\bar{AE})^2$$ and solve for $\bar{AE}$.

Comment: Oh, I did not realise this question was so simple. Thanks ! =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't even have to bother with similarity here (yes they are similar, but it doesn't matter).

Let $\angle ACB = \angle CED = \theta$. That means that $\angle ECD = 90^{\circ} - \theta$ by the angle sum of $\triangle CDE$.

That means that $\triangle ACE$ is a right triangle allowing to to apply Pythagoras' Theorem to it. So $AE = \sqrt{AC^2 + CE^2}=25$.